# can only concateanate tuple (not "int") to tuple

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Can someone fix this code for me? This is a basic code for filling a square with a smaller image.

```
import random
import uuid
from PIL import Image

run_id = uuid.uuid1()

print(f'Processing run_id: {run_id}')

img1 = Image.open('1.png')

bg = Image.new('RGB', (1600, 1600))

rectangle_width = 160
rectangle_height = 160

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        rectangle_x = i*160
        rectangle_y = j*160
    
        bg.paste(img1, [
            (rectangle_x, rectangle_y),
            (rectangle_x + rectangle_width, rectangle_y + rectangle_height)], img1) 

bg.show()
```

I am getting an error

```
File "c:\Users\manis\Desktop\Pixel Ores\sample 4.py", line 16, in <module>
bg.paste(img1, [
File "C:\Users\manis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", 
line 1563, in paste
box += (box[0] + size[0], box[1] + size[1])
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

..................................................................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The box to paste the image into needs to be a 4-tuple instead of a list of 2 2-tuples:

```
bg.paste(
    img1,
    (rectangle_x, rectangle_y, rectangle_x + rectangle_width, rectangle_y + rectangle_height),
    img1
)
```

According to the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste):

> The `box` argument is either a 2-tuple giving the upper left corner, a
> 4-tuple defining the left, upper, right, and lower pixel coordinate,
> or `None` (same as (0, 0)).

Comment: Thank you so much!